# New "Missing annotation" error in flowjs 0.54.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

After switching to flow 0.54.0 the following code fragment:

```
function runKarmaTest() {
    const KARMA_CONFIG = {};
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        new karma.Server(KARMA_CONFIG, function (exitCode) {
            if (exitCode === 0) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(exitCode);
            }
        }).start();
    });
}
```

reports the following error:

```
Error: scripts/runKarma.js:76
               v----------------------------------------
 76:    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 77:            new karma.Server(KARMA_CONFIG, function (exitCode) {
 78:                    if (exitCode === 0) {
...:
 84:    });
        -^ type parameter `R` of constructor call. Missing annotation
```

in the line `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` and I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: which version of Flow were you previously using? 0.52 or 0.53

Comment: I just upgrade from 0.53.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Promise<void>` annotation in the `runKarmaTest` function solves this problem:

```
function runKarmaTest(): Promise<void> {
    const KARMA_CONFIG = {};
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        new karma.Server(KARMA_CONFIG, function (exitCode) {
            if (exitCode === 0) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(exitCode);
            }
        }).start();
    });
}
```

I'm still not sure:

- why this annotation is needed in 0.54 and not before
- why the flow `Type Inference` cannot deduce it from the missing parameter in resolve

Comment: Flow requires that you annotate module boundaries. You're right that in many cases it could infer them, but it would require global type inference which would be extremely slow on large codebases. Flow can run much faster if it only needs to do type inference on one module at a time. I'm not sure why this annotation is needed now, but I would guess that there was a bug that was fixed.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the thing it wants to know is the type of value wrapped by the promise. In this case it looks like it's just `undefined`, since the success case doesn't give any value. You can probably annotate the function that returns this as returning a `Promise<void>` or something like that to make this error go away.

It is curious that this happens in 0.54 and not before, though.

Comment: The new problem was actually not the `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {` line reported by flow but the missing annotation in the `function runKarmaTest()` definition itself.